# &amp; php post receive problem

Tags: php, javascript

my ajax request is

```
ajaxRequest.send("var1=" + var1.value + "&var2=" + var2.value + "&var3=" + var3.value);
```

but the browser sends the request as

```
var1= hello&amp;var2= world&amp;var3=1
```

php side receives the data as a post

```
$variable1 = $_POST['var1'];
$variable2 = $_POST['var2'];
$variable3 = $_POST['var3'];
```

only the first variable receives the data. The las two variables do not receive any data.

the correct format of sending the request as i know is

```
var1= hello&var2= world&var3=1
```

But why did the browser appended some useless characters that made the php side unable to recognise what has been sent ?

Comment: did u try to debug all `var1.value`, `var2.value` and `var3.value`

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in your client-side javascript rather than server side; I doubt it has anything to do with PHP. I've added Javascript to the tags. What Javascript library are you using for the Ajax? (that should also be added to the tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your ampersands are encoded before sending the request to the browser. This way, the next variable is not recognized. Instead, the first variable contains: `hello&amp;var2= world&amp;var3=1`. I don't know which javascript library you're using, but it seems to me either you are using the wrong function arguments (maybe you need to inject an object instead of a string?), or the function wrongly encodes the string.

Take [jQuery's ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for example, query parameters are passed as an object, like this:

```
var data = { 'var1' : var1.value, 'var2' : var2.value };
$.ajax('/ajax/', { 'data': data});
```

Answer (score 0):

What happen's when you use urlencode ?

You could put the data string into a variable first then urlencode that veriable and pass the variable inside the ajaxRequest.send